# Problema en edición de registros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems, activerecord

Estoy viendo los vídeos del curso de *ruby on rails 4* y en estos momentos tengo un error al intentar modificar un registro de la tabla de productos con `id` 23.

Por alguna razón toma el `id` 16, el cual edita y luego hace un ciclo desde el número 16 hasta el 23. Pero sólo se modifica el dato 16 y no el que se requiere modificar.

Controlador productos:

```
class ProductosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_producto, except: [:index, :new, :create]
    before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy, :edit]
    before_action :authenticate_public!, only: [:show, :index]

    def index
        @producto = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).ultimos
        respond_to do |formato|
            formato.html
            formato.json
            formato.pdf {render template: "productos/reporteproductos", pdf: "reporteproductos", layout: "pdf.html"}
        end
    end

    def show
        @producto.update_visitas
        @comentarios_producto = ComentariosProducto.new
        respond_to do |formato|
            formato.html
            formato.pdf {render template: "productos/reporteproducto", pdf: "reporteproductos", layout: "pdf.html"}
        end
    end

    def new
        @producto = Producto.new
        @categorias = Categorium.all
    end

    def create
        #@nuevoproducto = Producto.new(nombre: params[:producto][:nombre], precio: params[:producto][:precio], descripcion: params[:producto][:descripcion])
        @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)
        @producto.categoria = params[:categories]
        if @producto.save
            redirect_to @producto
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def update
        if Producto.update(producto_params)
            redirect_to @producto
        else
            render :edit
        end
        #Producto.update_attributes({nombre: params[:nombre], precio: params[:precio], descripcion: params[:descripcion]})
    end

    def destroy
        @producto.destroy
        redirect_to productos_path
    end

    def edit
    end

    private
    def set_producto
        @producto = Producto.find(params[:id])
    end
    def producto_params
        params.require(:producto).permit(:nombre,:precio,:descripcion,:imagen,:categories)
    end
end
```

Modelo productos:

```
class Producto < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comentarios_productos
    has_many :has_category
    has_many :categorium, through: :has_category
    validates :nombre, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :precio, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
    validates :descripcion, presence: true, length: {minimum: 20}

    before_create :set_visitas
    after_create :save_categorias

    has_attached_file :imagen, styles: { medium: "1280x720", thumb: "800x600", mini: "400x200" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :imagen, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    scope :ultimos, ->{ order("created_at DESC") }

    def categoria=(valor)
        @categorias = valor
    end

    def update_visitas
        self.update(visitas: self.visitas + 1)
    end

    private
    def set_visitas
        self.visitas ||= 0
    end

    def save_categorias
        unless @categorias.nil?
            @categorias.each do |categoria_id|
                HasCategory.create(categorium_id: categoria_id, producto_id: self.id)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Formulario edición productos:

```
<% name ||= "Crear" %>
<h2><%= name %> producto</h2>
<%= form_for(@producto) do |producto| %>
  <% if @producto.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>No es posible guardar el producto debido a las siguientes razones:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @producto.errors.full_messages.each do |errores| %>
          <div class="be-red white">
            <li>* <%= errores %></li>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= producto.label :nombre, "Nombre:"%><br />
    <%= producto.text_field :nombre, placeholder: "Nombre", autofocus: true, class:"form_control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= producto.label :precio, "Precio:" %><br />
    <%= producto.text_field :precio, placeholder: "Precio",autocomplete: "off", class:"form_control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= producto.label :descripcion, "Descripción:" %><br />
    <%= producto.text_area :descripcion, placeholder: "Puedes ingresar aquí una descripción del producto",autocomplete: "off", class:"form_control", style:"height:200px;" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= producto.label :imagen, placeholder: "Puedes subir una foto del producto:" %><br />
    <%= producto.file_field :imagen, class:"form_control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Categorías: </label>
    <% @categorias.each do |categorizar| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= check_box_tag "categories[]", categorizar.id %>
        <%= categorizar.nombre %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= producto.submit name, class:"btn be-red white" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Volver", '/productos' %>
```

Logs:

```
Started PATCH "/productos/23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 19:23:57 -0400
Processing by ProductosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oCRHD7nP70E0GfhJwZ44wMxLa1hld9kGbR2CaJV09zTZu5JUbeXy+dFaykTBqdU9M9OQvtBkF3pIazzHyk+IpA==", "producto"=>{"nombre"=>"muñecovodoo22222", "precio"=>"99999", "descripcion"=>"comentario del producto editado", "imagen"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000116e8c08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170731-11864-26ld81.jpeg>, @original_filename="pikachu tortuga.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"producto[imagen]\"; filename=\"pikachu tortuga.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Editar", "id"=>"23"}
  [1m[36mProducto Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "productos".* FROM "productos" WHERE "productos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 23], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUsuario Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" WHERE "usuarios"."id" = ? ORDER BY "usuarios"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mProducto Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "productos".* FROM "productos"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/6538d54b2a28bff692172b14ce82938820170731-11864-1ywgref.jpeg"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" -auto-orient -resize "1280x720" "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/0c5a0256b649485b0815c713d45cbc8d20170731-11864-w1ross"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" -auto-orient -resize "800x600" "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/0c5a0256b649485b0815c713d45cbc8d20170731-11864-1u2bcb9"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/1b3d8e96c273f588268246540fc55c6920170731-11864-1qoo9ti.jpeg[0]" -auto-orient -resize "400x200" "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/0c5a0256b649485b0815c713d45cbc8d20170731-11864-rgegwt"
  [1m[36mProducto Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "productos" WHERE "productos"."nombre" = ? AND ("productos"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?[0m  [["nombre", "muñecovodoo22222"], ["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/rpozoh/AppData/Local/Temp/6538d54b2a28bff692172b14ce82938820170731-11864-1s47kcq.jpeg"
  [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "productos" SET "nombre" = ?, "precio" = ?, "descripcion" = ?, "imagen_file_name" = ?, "imagen_file_size" = ?, "imagen_updated_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "productos"."id" = ?[0m  [["nombre", "muñecovodoo22222"], ["precio", 99999], ["descripcion", "comentario del producto editado"], ["imagen_file_name", "pikachu_tortuga.jpeg"], ["imagen_file_size", 64528], ["imagen_updated_at", "2017-07-31 23:23:57.309654"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-31 23:23:58.247826"], ["id", 16]]
[paperclip] deleting C:/Users/rpozoh/Documents/Ruby/website-pokehomy/public/system/productos/imagens/000/000/016/original/15056318_1664282233597680_232155783732829081_n.jpg
[paperclip] deleting C:/Users/rpozoh/Documents/Ruby/website-pokehomy/public/system/productos/imagens/000/000/016/medium/15056318_1664282233597680_232155783732829081_n.jpg
[paperclip] deleting C:/Users/rpozoh/Documents/Ruby/website-pokehomy/public/system/productos/imagens/000/000/016/thumb/15056318_1664282233597680_232155783732829081_n.jpg
[paperclip] deleting C:/Users/rpozoh/Documents/Ruby/website-pokehomy/public/system/productos/imagens/000/000/016/mini/15056318_1664282233597680_232155783732829081_n.jpg
```

Esto es el log editado, la primera petición es para editar producto 23, pero después cambia al 16.

Comment: ¿Qué acción estás ejecutando cuándo se genera el error? ¿Podrías verificar que estés tomando el log correcto/completo? Este muestra las llamadas a la base de datos, pero no muestra la solicitud realizada al controlador.

Comment: El log completo no pude colocarlo por limite de caracteres, pero este problema aparece al intentar modificar un registro de la base de datos con active records

 def update
        if Producto.update(producto_params)
            redirect_to @producto
        else
            render :edit
        end
        #Producto.update_attributes({nombre: params[:nombre], precio: params[:precio], descripcion: params[:descripcion]})
end

def producto_params
        params.require(:producto).permit(:nombre,:precio,:descripcion,:imagen,:categories)
end

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar otro log, pero esta vez sólo incluye el bloque con  la información de la petición y respuesta del controlador. De igual forma, agrega la acción `update` que describes en el comentario anterior para poder tener un formato legible.

Comment: Listo, acabo de editar el log y coloque otro extracto donde si esta apareciendo la solicitud, ahora veo que justo antes del update esta cambiando el id del producto que se requiere modificar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en la acción `update` del controlador `ProductosController`, en específico en la siguiente línea:

```
if Producto.update(producto_params)
```

El problema con `Producto.update` es que estás actualizando **todos** los productos, por eso toma desde el primero que encuentra (i.e. `id = 16`) hasta el último que has agregado al momento (i.e. `id = 23`).

Lo que debes hacer es primer buscar el producto con el `id` correcto (en este caso `23`) y posteriormente actualizarlo. En el código ya realizas dicha búsqueda con el método `set_producto` (el cual ejecutas en el *callback* `before_action`); esto significa que, al iniciar tu acción, ya tienes definida la variable `@producto`, por lo tanto actualiza ese producto.

En resumen, cambia `Producto` en la acción `update` del controlador por `@producto`, así:

```
def update
  if @producto.update(producto_params)
    redirect_to @producto
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Estimado, eso me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias.